# Как динамически менять запрос в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос вида

```
select что-то там 
 from джоин нномер раз,
      джоин нномер два
    where 1=1
    and объединение 1
    and объединение 2
    and условие 1
    and условие 2
```

Как нацчить запрос по условию не делать джоин и не выполнять условие? Если параметр ,например, передан пустой?

Неужели нужно писать 100500 запросов?

Comment: Собирать запрос по кускам. Если массив джойнов пуст, не делать джойнов. Если в условии пустой параметр (на самом деле, пустой параметр может вполне валидным значением) - не добавлять условие в запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "select что-то там ";
$query += "from джоин номер раз,";
$query += "джоин номер два,";
$query += "where 1=1"
if(условие){$query+="and объединение 1"}
if(условие){$query+="and объединение 2"}
if(условие){$query+="and условие 1"}
if(условие){$query+="and условие 2"}
```

В результате в переменной $query у нас лежит нужный запрос. Как-то так, только внимательней с пробелами